# Error linking libxml ios

Tags: ios, xcode8, libxml2, linker-errors, kissxml

I am running an iOS project. I am using Xcode 8 and I can't compile my project on device and successfully run it on simulator. It was successfully compiled with Xcode 7.2

I am using KissXML with cocoapods and this is using libxml2.2.dylib framework.

https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML

I did many things:

- added `libxml2.2.dylib` file to Xcode content
- added `-lxml2` to other linker flag
- added `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2` to header search path
- added `$(inherited)` to processor Macros

but I couldn't run project.  I am always getting this error.

```
    "_xmlStrdup", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNamespaceNode setName:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlDocSetRootElement", 

    referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode nodesForXPath:error:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlXPathFreeContext", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode nodesForXPath:error:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlXPathEvalExpression", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode nodesForXPath:error:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlUnlinkNode", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode nodesForXPath:error:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlXPathNewContext", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode nodesForXPath:error:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlSaveNoEmptyTags", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode XMLStringWithOptions:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlIndentTreeOutput", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode XMLStringWithOptions:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlNodeDump", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode XMLStringWithOptions:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlNodeGetContent", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode stringValue] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlNewDoc", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode nodesForXPath:error:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlNodeSetName", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode setName:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlCopyDoc", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode copyWithZone:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlXPathFreeObject", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode nodesForXPath:error:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlCopyNode", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode copyWithZone:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlCopyProp", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode copyWithZone:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlCopyDtd", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode copyWithZone:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlFreeDtd", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode dealloc] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlKeepBlanksDefault", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLDocument initWithData:options:error:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLDocument.o)
          ___23+[DDXMLNode initialize]_block_invoke in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlNewText", referenced from:
          +[DDXMLNode textWithStringValue:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          -[DDXMLAttributeNode setStringValue:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlFreeNs", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode dealloc] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          +[DDXMLNode removeNamespace:fromNode:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          +[DDXMLNode removeAllNamespacesFromNode:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          -[DDXMLAttributeNode dealloc] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          -[DDXMLAttributeNode setURI:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlNewNs", referenced from:
          +[DDXMLNode namespaceWithName:stringValue:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          -[DDXMLNode setURI:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          +[DDXMLNode recursiveMigrateNamespace:to:node:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          +[DDXMLNode recursiveFixDefaultNamespacesInNode:withNewRoot:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          -[DDXMLAttributeNode detach] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          -[DDXMLAttributeNode setURI:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlSetStructuredErrorFunc", referenced from:
          ___23+[DDXMLNode initialize]_block_invoke in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlAddPrevSibling", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLElement insertChild:atIndex:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLElement.o)
      "_initGenericErrorDefaultFunc", referenced from:
          ___23+[DDXMLNode initialize]_block_invoke in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlCopyNamespace", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode copyWithZone:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlAddChild", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLElement addAttribute:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLElement.o)
          -[DDXMLElement addChild:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLElement.o)
          -[DDXMLElement insertChild:atIndex:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLElement.o)
      "_xmlNewPI", referenced from:
          +[DDXMLNode processingInstructionWithName:stringValue:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlStrcmp", referenced from:
          -[GCDWebDAVServer(Methods) performPROPFIND:] in GCDWebDAVServer.o
          __XMLChildWithName in GCDWebDAVServer.o
      "_xmlStrEqual", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLElement _elementsForName:localName:prefix:uri:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLElement.o)
          -[DDXMLElement _hasAttributeWithName:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLElement.o)
          -[DDXMLElement _removeAttributeForName:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLElement.o)
          -[DDXMLElement attributeForName:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLElement.o)
          -[DDXMLElement _removeNamespaceForPrefix:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLElement.o)
          -[DDXMLElement namespaceForPrefix:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLElement.o)
          -[DDXMLElement _recursiveResolveNamespaceForPrefix:atNode:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLElement.o)
          ...
      "_xmlEncodeSpecialChars", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode setStringValue:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          -[DDXMLNamespaceNode setStringValue:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          -[DDXMLAttributeNode setStringValue:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlFreeProp", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode dealloc] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          +[DDXMLNode removeAttribute:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          +[DDXMLNode removeAllAttributesFromNode:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlFreeNode", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode dealloc] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          +[DDXMLNode removeChild:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          +[DDXMLNode removeAllChildrenFromNode:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlNewComment", referenced from:
          +[DDXMLNode commentWithStringValue:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlNewProp", referenced from:
          +[DDXMLNode attributeWithName:stringValue:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          +[DDXMLNode attributeWithName:URI:stringValue:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlBufferCreate", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode XMLStringWithOptions:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlBufferFree", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode XMLStringWithOptions:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlNewNode", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLElement initWithName:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLElement.o)
          -[DDXMLElement initWithName:URI:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLElement.o)
          -[DDXMLElement initWithName:stringValue:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLElement.o)
      "_xmlStrQEqual", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLElement attributeForName:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLElement.o)
      "_xmlParseMemory", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLDocument initWithData:options:error:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLDocument.o)
      "_xmlReadMemory", referenced from:
          -[GCDWebDAVServer(Methods) performPROPFIND:] in GCDWebDAVServer.o
          -[GCDWebDAVServer(Methods) performLOCK:] in GCDWebDAVServer.o
      "_xmlDocGetRootElement", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLDocument rootElement] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLDocument.o)
      "_xmlSearchNs", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLElement elementsForName:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLElement.o)
          -[DDXMLAttributeNode URI] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlXPathRegisterNs", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode nodesForXPath:error:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlNodeSetContent", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode setStringValue:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          -[DDXMLAttributeNode setStringValue:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
      "_xmlFree", referenced from:
          -[DDXMLNode setStringValue:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          -[DDXMLNode stringValue] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          -[DDXMLNamespaceNode setName:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          -[DDXMLNamespaceNode setStringValue:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)
          -[DDXMLAttributeNode setStringValue:] in libKissXML.a(DDXMLNode.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: i've followed all instructions. header search path, other linker flag and also i added libxml2.2.dylib file. It is working on xcode 7.2 but not xcode 8. And xcode 8 logs a weird message: ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib, missing required architecture arm64 in file

Comment: Did u got any solution for it? I am facing the same problem.. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: This happened after I tried to fix a red error icon and removed the libxml dylib that was previously in the project.

Comment: Line missing from pbxproj looks like:

  EF8BFFD11721DFA500E6C971 /* libxml2.dylib in Frameworks */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = EF8BFFD01721DFA500E6C971 /* libxml2.dylib */; };